# python implicit casting string into datetime object

Tags: python, string, datetime, date, casting

I know that there are various post similar to this.
and well aware of the `strptime` and `strftime` functions.

My question is a little different.

What is the simplest way in python to implicitly cast string into a date/dateime object.

Or explicitly, a function that will accept either a string that represents a date or a date object.

Similar to SQL `date_object = 'string_of_date'`

I guess that

```
cast_date=lambda x:x if type(x)=='datetime' else strptime(x,'%%%')#dosen't really work
cast_date=lambda x:strptime(str(x),'%%%') #edit
```

or similar will work but i rather use something native if exists.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use "if type(x)==something" (and definitely not "if type(x)==some string", which will always fail) - this may still be a leftover in some old online tutorials, but please learn the preferred idiom "if isinstance(x, sometype)".  (Hey! I'm as smart as Raymond Hettinger!)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module. It has a great date time parser.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> print parse("1:00PM")
2011-12-11 13:00:00
>>> print parse("1/1/2008")
2008-01-01 00:00:00
>>> print type(parse("1/1/2008"))
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Combine that together with a type check like this:

```
my_datetime = parse(item) if isinstance(item, str) or isinstance(item, unicode) else item
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native datetime cast in Python.  Your little helper function looks like a reasonable approach.  Do consider using *isinstance* instead of an exact type check (to allow for subclasses of datetime).

Comment: thanks for the help, it would be nice  to have a more pythonic way to handle dates in python.

Comment: @sinaiy I am happy to be of help :-)